# EF linq/lambda .contains(list[String])?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

is there any way to evaluate if a string contains some of the elements of a list or all the elements of the list? using linq to entities?

i have been trying to use predicateBuilder and others but im not %100 into thoses.

EDIT

something like:

```
string[] words = searchString.Split(' ');

var resultado = db.users
                        .Where(u => u.fullName.contains(words) )
                                .Select(s => new { user_id = s.id_user, nombre = s.fullName})
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: And the answer is : yes. More precise question, maybe ?

Comment: Yes you can do this using contains method

Comment: contains can take a list as argument?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to reverse your use of `Contains` to check the `words` collection for the `fullName`:

```
string[] words = searchString.Split(' ');

var resultado = db.users
    .Where(u => words.Contains(u.fullName))
    .Select(s => new { user_id = s.id_user, nombre = s.fullName})
    .ToList();
```

That will match **one** item in the `words` array.

To match **all** of `words` in a user's `fullName`, use `All`:

```
var resultado = db.users
    .Where(u => words.All(w => u.fullName.Contains(w))
    .Select(s => new { user_id = s.id_user, nombre = s.fullName})
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What about matching all in order? Something like matching `Bill Gates` when `searchString = "Bi Gat"` but not matching  `Bill Gates` when `searchString = "Gat Bi"`

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do with [intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx)

```
 IEnumerable<string> first = ...;
 IEnumerable<string> second= ...;
var duplicates = first.Intersect(second);
```

and doest contains

```
bool contains = duplicates.Any();
```