# Where Not in List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a `List<string>` that contains a number of string values.
Can I filter a collection when doing a query with a list instead of a single value?

Something like this:

```
List<string> slist = new List<string>() { "val 1", "val 2", "val 3" };
var q = (from s in ctx.Shipments
         where !s.ShipName.ToList().Contains(slist)).ToList()
```

Comment: Found my answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816820/ef-linq-lamda-containsliststring   Just needed to reverse the use of collections being compared.

Comment: Every time you call `ToList()` you put all data in memory.

Comment: Note that something like `"Serenity".ToList()` works similarly to `.ToCharArray()`. It gives a list of the individual `char` values (letters) of which the string is composed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is `!slist.Contains(s.ShipName)` like:

```
(from s in ctx.Shipments 
 where !slist.Contains(s.ShipName)
).ToList();
```

You may see this article for [creating IN query with LINQ](http://www.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/)

Answer (score 1):

```
from sn in ctx.ShipNames
where !slist.Contains(sn.Name)
select sn.Shipment
```

May be you can go from the ShipName entity

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
List<string> slist = new List<string>() {"val 1", "val 2", "val 3"};
(from s in ctx.Shipments where !slist.Contains(s.ShipName).ToList();
```

This way you will get all the records of the Shipments, whose name isn't included in the `slist`.